I cannot access my application on localhost 8080. It only shows default Login Page. And then it says Not Authorized
My application has started on port 8080, but when I try to access it on web browser with localhost8080, it shows a default login page. And when I try to include my end point "/register", it says Not Authorized.
Below is my SecurityConfig Class.
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter; 


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider; 
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    
    
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll() // Permit access to the login page
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) 
            
            .formLogin() // Specify form login configuration
                .loginPage("/register") // Specify your custom login page URL
                .permitAll(); // Permit access to the custom login page

    }
    

I have tried to include to security dependencies. But still problem
